# Sudo Won't Work after change/mistake in Path env

Tags: macos, node.js, environment-variables, sudo, npm

I'm a Mac newbie and just upgraded to Node.js 0.67. After running node, the installer says "Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH."

And I try to run node but as expected, it doesn't run without the path change.

So not really knowing what I'm doing (yes!), after some research I do this:

export "PATH=/usr/local/bin"

And node runs. But sudo doesn't. Which I think means I screwed up the environment variables.

sudo: command not found

Then in another Terminal window (that was open when I messed this up), sudo does respond; both windows have the same path. But in that window, npm is no longer available.

Can anyone help get me back to sudo stability?

Comment: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo` on a Macintosh lives in `/usr/bin`.

Make sure `/usr/bin` is in your `$PATH` environment and you should be okay.

And to do that, in the context of your question above, do something like:

```
export "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
```

The idea here being that you are *appending* a new search path to the already existing list in your PATH environment variable.

[Here is a potentially useful tutorial](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable/) you can refer to.

Comment: thanks--that was fast! how can I tell what's in the $Path environment? and can I append usr/bin through the same method?

Comment: Ok--fixed it! Thanks so much. export "PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin" did the trick. both sudo and node work...now for npm :) Thanks!